# How can I prevent ColdFusion from converting HTML Entity?

Tags: coldfusion, html-entities, coldfusion-8

Let's assume I have data store that I cannot change.

Within that data store I have a table of string values:

- `BROWN`
- `BLUE & RED`
- `YELLOW &amp; PURPLE`
- `BLACK`

Note that the values can contain both HTML entities and their coutnerparts (i.e. `&amp;` and `&`).

Now, I want to output those values as input values (checkboxes).

With no manipulation, ColdFusion converts the `&amp;` to `&`. When that checkbox is selected and I validate it against the data store, it fails, since `YELLOW &amp; PURPLE` (data store value) does not equal `YELLOW & PURPLE` (form value).

Here is the current [pseudo] code I'm using to output the checkboxes:

```
<cfquery name="LOCAL.qColors">
    SELECT
        COLOR
    FROM    COLORS
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="LOCAL.qColors">
    <div>
    <input
        id="color-#CURRENTROW#"
        type="checkbox"
        class="checkbox"
        name="colors"
        value="#COLOR#"
        #IIF(ListFindNoCase(FORM.colors, COLOR), "'checked'", "")# />
    <label for="color-#CURRENTROW#">
        #COLOR#
    </label>
    </div>
</cfoutput>
```

How can I prevent ColdFusion from decoding the HTML entity and just using the exact string I want?

Comment: Please post your code that renders the `<input>` elements, as well as your code that processes the submitted form.

Comment: "With no manipulation, ColdFusion converts[...]". Can you please provide code that demonstrates this? Cheers.

Comment: What is the nature of this data store?  Is it a database table?  If so, is there another field that would be more suitable for a checkbox value?

Comment: Why are you using the same string for the `value` and the `label` of the checkboxen? Seems you might have some kind of `ID` value you could use that would not get mucked up by encoding, and would be easier to compare.

Comment: @DanBracuk It is a database table. The database is not normalized and the data is not "clean", per se. So, no, there no other suitable field. If so, I would not be asking this question.

Comment: @ScottStroz Sorry, but as I stated in my first line, the data is what it is - no ID. There's really nothing I can do about the actual data, other than how I display it and use in on the fron-end. Again, I'm not looking for help with the database, but I want to find a way to do what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are, it has nothing to do with ColdFusion and it's actually your browser (correctly) interpreting HTML entities in the HTML source of your page.  If you have any string which you do NOT want your browser to parse as HTML, then you must escape it.  Use the HTMLEditFormat() function when outputting the value.

This might be especially important if your values ever contain a double quote.  And as a general precaution, **NEVER** output naked (unescaped) text into your webpage that you don't expect to have safe parseable HTML in it for both display issues as well as security concerns.

**ColdFusion 9 and lower**

```
#HTMLEditFormat( arbitraryValue )# 
<input name="myOptions" type="checkbox" value="#HTMLEditFormat( arbitraryValue )#">
```

**ColdFusion 10+**

```
#encodeForHTML( arbitraryValue )# 
<input name="myOptions" type="checkbox" value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute( arbitraryValue )#">
```

You will then see in the HTML source of the page that "**BLUE & RED**" becomes "**BLUE &amp; RED**" and "**YELLOW &amp; PURPLE**" becomes "**YELLOW &amp;amp; PURPLE**".  When that HTML is parsed, the original value will be used and submitted by the form.

Comment: Right idea, wrong detail.  You don't apply the htmledit format to the value attribute, you apply it to the text that gets displayed to the user indicating.

Comment: Actually you would want to apply it to the value attribute as well as the display in order to compensate for any conflicting characters. Another way of looking at it is what if the data had an greater than or less than symbol or even quotes in it, if that got put into the value with no formatting then the page will render incorrectly.  It might also handle the root issue here when compared on the processing end as well although I'd want to see the actual code causing CF to change the DB values when put into the input's value attribute.

Comment: Dan, you absolutely escape the value attribute.  Especially in this scenario when it contains HTML which isn't intended for the browser to parse.  I agree that you would also escape the text in the label (or ANYWHERE else it displayed) but since I didn't include a label in my code sample that was kind of moot.  I updated the code to show the value being escaped in both the label and the input value.

Comment: And I updated to use the newer encoding functions. :P

Comment: This was a rare event for me.  I actually wrote some code and tested my theory before making my comment.  Since Brad and Snipe think I'm wrong, I suggest they do the same thing.  The nature of my test was to try various things in my ColdFusion source code and see how it turned out when I did a View Source in the browser.

Comment: This works perfectly for what I need. Didn't realize I could use this function for this. Thank you @BradWood

Comment: Thanks for the CF10 example Adrian.  I *almost* mentioned that, but avoided it when I saw the question was tagged CF8 since I didn't want to confuse the OP with code that wouldn't work for him.